# how to save a link for programming

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment due for my class where I need to save a file from a link to use it in the program.

This is what I have to open the file:

```
with open("words.txt") as file:
    for word in file.readlines():
        word = word.strip()
        if len(word) == 3 or len(word) == 4:
            words.append(word)
```

It outputs this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'words.txt'
```

This is how I have it saved on my laptop:
[image]

Am I supposed to save it differently?

Comment: Maybe your script is not running in the same directory as your file? I see that your file is in `C:\Users\rosac\Downloads`; is your script in the same place?  What if you replace `"words.txt"` in your script with `"C:/Users/rosac/Downloads/words.txt"`?

Comment: You can use \\ in place of \ otherwise path like *C: \Zebronic\tiger* will be evaluated to *C: \Zebronic    iger*. `\t` is tab character.

Comment: Rosa, it looks like you have an answer, please mark it as accepted or at least vote up.

Answer (score 1):

Your file "words.txt" need to be at the same place of your script if you to want use 'open("words.txt")'.

2 solutions :

- You move your "words.txt" to the same folder as your python script
- you replace `open("words.txt")` by `open("C:\Users\rosac\Downloads\words.txt")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to path your script the full path to 'words.txt':

```
with open("C:\Users\rosac\Downloads\words.txt") as file:
    for word in file.readlines():
        word = word.strip()
        if len(word) == 3 or len(word) == 4:
            words.append(word)
```

Depending on your editor you may need to use `/` instead of `\` for your path slashes. You could also change your working directory:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:\Users\rosac\Downloads\")
```

and then you can open your file:

```
with open("words.txt") as file:
...
```

Comment: If either solution worked well for you, click the check mark under to show that this question has an answer and it will move out of the queue. Happy to help!